# countif using the same range of cells across mulitple worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

My workbook has an individual worksheet per day of the month 1,2,3, etc.

On each worksheet cells C8:C34 contain numbers which may be duplicated (0-999).

I would like to calculate the total times a particular number occurs, I'm already doing this with successive countif statements but this seems a very longwinded and messy approach. Is there a simpler method for achieving this?

Current code:

```
=(COUNTIFS('1'!$C$8:$C$34,C1)+(COUNTIFS('2'!$C$8:$C$34,C1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It the total count of sheets is known, then

```
=COUNTIF('1'!$C$8:$C$34,C1)+COUNTIF('2'!$C$8:$C$34,C1)+COUNTIF('3'!$C$8:$C$34,C1)
```

can be replaced with

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"1";"2";"3"}&"!$C$8:$C$34"),C1))
```

There `{"1";"2";"3"}` is an array literal with the sheet names. The `SUMPRODUCT` will implicitly work as an array formula and will take this array literal as "1"; "2"; "3" one after the other and will perform 3 single `COUNTIF` with different sheet names in `INDIRECT`.

If the sheet names are ongoing numbers, then this could also be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ROW($1:$3)&"!$C$8:$C$34"),C2))
```

There `ROW($1:$3)` will be `{1;2;3}` in array context. While concatenating with `&` the numbers will be implicitly converted to strings.

Comment: '=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT(ROW($1:$3)&"!$C$8:$C$34"),C2))' worked like a charm, I really appreciate the explanation as to how it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Two many countifs?
Not good, 
Instead, use a pivot table.

Explanation:
Let's say your Excel sheet looks like this:
[image]

Select "Insert Pivot Table" in the "Insert" Tab, 
In the Pivot Table Fields (right column) Put "Label" in Columns 
and Put Labels in Values (just drag and drop). Change Values to "Count of Labels" instead of Sum of Labels, 
and that's the end of the story.

count if (and it's best friend Sum if) are expensive operations, use them moderately. Pivot Table are cheap in the sense they are optimized.

This is what the results would look like:
[image]

Comment: I think problem is there because of data from multiple sheets need to be used to count the numbers. your answer will work if we have all the data in the one single sheet.

Comment: Below this table create another Pivot Table - per sheet. Then count all of them together. Alternatively, of course, try to group them to a single spreadsheet; it's a hard job but it is a best practice.

Comment: Thanks Hila, but it sounds like I would just be replacing multiple countif statements with multiple pivot tables whilst losing some formatting functionality.  My numbers are actually hotel room numbers and the current set up allows me to organise the rooms by floor (1st digit) as well as type (last 2 digits)

Comment: Thought so, add Left (Label, 1) and Right (label, 2) as columns to your original tables, so you can Pivot some more without losing functionality.